# way to set connection string for database migration in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP MVC 5 app with code first migrations enabled.  Whenever I publish it to a server, it adds an extra connection string to the Web.Config file along with a "parameter" element, and it breaks the site until I replace it.  It looks like:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <contexts>
        <context type="MyApp.DataLayer.MyContext, MyApp">
            <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MyApp.DataLayer.MyContext, MyApp], [MyApp.Migrations.Configuration, MyApp]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <parameters>
                    <parameter value="MyContext_DatabasePublish" />
                </parameters>
            </databaseInitializer>
        </context>
    </contexts>
</entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyContext_DatabasePublish" connectionString="MyContext_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I presume that extra connection string is for the database migrations, is that right?  All I have to do to get things working is replace the connection string with the one above it, so replace `MyContext_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString` with `Data Source=SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI` for example.

First, is that connection string even needed?  This is all in dev, and my migrations were all done from my local machine.

If it is needed, is there a way to keep it from coming in as `MyContext_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString` and instead come in as the connection string that works so I don't have to manually replace it every time I publish an update?

Thank you in advance for any information and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See post here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2012/06/12/deployment-in-visual-studio-2012-rc-using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations/

This occurs when you setup code first migrations so that you can define a privileged account to run your migrations without having to elevate the privileges of your normal context user.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to deploy without having to manually edit that connection string, but the link was helpful in educating me on where the connection string is coming from.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it talks about that in one of the linked articles from the page. You basically define the connection for it in your prod transform config.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I got it now.  Thanks again!